# Implementing a "Like" button and showing users who clicked it

Tags: drupal

Our website is powered by Drupal 7 and we are looking for a way to implement a "I am Interested" button/link on a particular node for registered users. The problem here is that we'd also like to be able to display all the usernames who have clicked this button/link.

The idea here is to provide our viewers with a simple way to be able to indicate interest in a particular topic, and essentially giving them an outlet to communicate to other users who have shown the same interest.

I've tried a number of different modules that other sources have suggested: "Flags, Dlike, LikeBtn, Rate Widget, etc." and unfortunately they don't seem to ultimately do what I'm looking for. I want to believe that there is some combination of modules that can perform these actions, so I would greatly appreciate any guidance that can be provided.

I do apologize for my ignorance in this type of development. Looking forward to growing into this community.

Cheers.

Comment: May be if you can describe what you need to do exactly, we can suggest **how** to use an existing module to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with the [Flag module](https://drupal.org/project/flag) (which you tried), and the Views module to display a list of users that have clicked the flag for a particular node.

Looks like [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69091/flags-recreate-the-poke-function) would help you out with the Views config to list users that have flagged a node (or poked a user in the example).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I've made some progress; however, I'm running into an issue now. I've installed Flags and the Drupal Like module. I have a flag link set on the node/content-type of choice (referred to as articles). The flag link text appears on all the article pages and is functional. Additionally, the view has been configured to display the username of those who have flagged an article. Unfortunately, when I flag one article, all other articles display my username as well. The purpose for this feature is for users to indicate interest on various articles uniquely. Much Appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like the Flag config is wrong. There should be a default "Bookmark" flag that basically does what you want. You could copy the setting from there.